# Forward biasing of diode bridge in a discontinuous mode operation of a three phase buck-boost derived power factor corrected converter

Tags: converter, bridge-rectifier, buck-boost, power-factor-correction

In this paper, they said that during mode 1 the diode bridge is forward biased because the output capacitor voltage is greater than peak line to line voltage but during mode 2 they are forward biased. How can it be possible when during all modes the output voltage is always greater than peak line to line voltage?

[image: Mode 1 operation of the converter]

[image]

[image]

Comment: God Pool - Hi, (a) As you're new here, please see the [tour] & [help] for the main site rules. (b) Please note the [site rule](/help/referencing) that when a post copies or adapts content (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) from elsewhere, that content must be correctly referenced. For online content, the source webpage / PDF / video etc. should be named & linked as a minimum (see the linked rule about references for offline books / articles). Therefore please [edit] your question to add the appropriate source reference (name & link) for that paper & remember to include references in future. Thanks